# Displaying Custom Webpart in every view of a List?

Tags: web-part, list, sharepoint-foundation, list-view, sharepoint-online

i have a List called "Persons" in a SharePoint 365 (aka Online). This List contains 4 or 5 Views (The administrator can add more view depend on the actual situation).

On the default list, I have a webpart in the top Navigation, for displaying some informations and a simple dropdown.

Now, when I change the view, the webpart disapears, because it's only on the default view page inserted. 
Does there exists any masterpage that uses the view, so that i can insert the webpart there? Or exists another solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each view of a list is a unique page. The only shared piece across the pages is the masterpage, but this is the same master page for all pages in your site.

Short of something highly customized, and I don't know if at all doable on O365, is to manually put the web part on each view page. It's a pain, but it'll work ;).

HTH

Comment: I hoped that there is another way as the master page... okay then I must live with it :).